# Siegel modular forms in Mathematica

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, modular-forms, computer-algebra, theta-functions, siegel-modular-forms

Is there a convenient way to work with Siegel modular forms in Mathematica? I am interested in doing analytic computations using the $\chi_{10}(\Omega)$ Siegel modular form, where $\Omega$ is the $2\times 2$ matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho & v \\
v & \sigma
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I am aware that Mathematica has built-in functions for Siegel Theta functions, but I am not sure if these can be used to get $\chi_{10}$. Are there any packages or functions that are specifically designed for working with these forms?

Comment: I would encourage you to add a computational-math tag ([tag:computer-algebra]?  I'm not sure what's appropriate).  Without it, the users most familiar with CAS's might not see your question.  Also, have you tried asking at [MathematicaSE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Thanks, I have also posted the question on [MathematicaSE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278678/siegel-modular-forms-in-mathematica).

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out the [documentation](http://www.siegelmodularforms.org/pages/degree3/) on Siegel Modular Forms by Yuen, Poor, Shurman, and King. It provides a variety of Mathematica and Maple notebooks.